# Building and Installing cx_Oracle with conda skeleton/ conda build not working

Tags: python-3.6, conda, pypi, cx-oracle, conda-build

I have installed the package cx_Oracle, using conda skeleton command on my Windows 64bits machine, within Anaconda python

> conda skeleton pypi cx_Oracle
>
> af5f7daad67d6820670d582dfc045/cx_Oracle-6.0rc1.tar.gz (200 KB) for cx_Oracle.
>
> Downloading cx_Oracle
>
> Using cached download
>
> Unpacking cx_Oracle...
>
> done

when I am checking the file/ directory  is finally set, I see it there

```
    File "C:\Anaconda3_version4.3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\skeletons\pypi.py", line 339, in skeletonize
    raise RuntimeError("directory already exists: %s" % dir_path)
RuntimeError: directory already exists: .\cx_oracle
```

but when I am calling it, it cannot be  found

```
  import cx_oracle
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-fa7af752f8a0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cx_oracle

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_oracle'
```

The directory of cx_Oracle contains the files,
and know I need to build the package with conda build:

> conda build cx_Oracle

Just so, it still  doesn't work

Provides me the following error:

```
Anaconda3_version4.3\conda-bld\cx_oracle_1499164
353203\_b_env\Library\include /Tcsrc/cx_Oracle.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Rel
ease\src/cx_Oracle.obj -DBUILD_VERSION=6.0rc1
error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
```

I do not understand what else is needed to finally install the package

Thanks for reading.

Comment: conda skeleton is for automatically building conda packages. It does not install packages. For more details, please refer to the documentation: https://conda.io/docs/build_tutorials/pkgs.html#build-a-simple-package-with-conda-skeleton-pypi

Comment: Thanks, but then it already exists, .\cx_Oracle is found, but now I understand it is not instaled

Comment: I have re-written, re-formulate the question. thanks for the help, after running conda build cx_oracle, I get the error described

Comment: Which Oracle client (e.g. Oracle Instant Client) do you have?  Do you have the correct VS Redistributables for that version of the Oracle client?

Comment: No, I have not installed any oracle client, do you meant in my own computer to install Oracle instant client for example,

Comment: I have now installed the Oracle-instantclient, version 11.2..0.4.0, but I am still getting the same error. thanks. (I installed it using conda oracle-instantclient)

Comment: `cl` is the Microsoft VC++ compiler, which conda build cannot find. There are a lot of problems of how to build Python packages using MSVC++ on SO, you have to search around and find them. But, why are you trying to build this yourself? Why not just `conda install cx_oracle`?

Comment: with "conda install cx_oracle", I get the version 5.3, and not the latest from the conda repository, I also get an error with a python 2.7 dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got a hint about this error thanks to the comments from @darthbith,

Building cx_Oracle requires you to have working C(++) compiler since cx_Oracle is written in C, not in Python even it's a Python module.